# How template synchronization works in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use template synchronization for subscription addon testing but when i clicked on template synchronization its not showing anything. i have copied two templates to template folder as you can see in documentation here

Things I have done for this in Global preference are :-

```
Save Template Revisions: Yes
Maximum Number of Revisions to Keep: 10
Save Template Revisions: Yes
Server path to site's templates: example.com/system/expressionengine/templates
```

Please tell me if anything else wrong or required.

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Just wrote all the below and then realised the problem - you're using the wrong path!

[image: Server path to site's templates]

You've put in a domain URL, or stated an invalid path. You need to start from the servers file root with `/`. Worth reading through the below, as this would have identified the issue also.

**The original response...**

If you have those settings from the beginning, before creating any templates, it's normally not a problem, but when you have existing templates (saving to the database), then you add/change those settings, nothing will happen.

Would be helpful to know what this exactly meant: "template synchronization its not showing anything", but I'll assume that it's not listing the templates you've added...?

You have to go and edit each and every individual template and turn on "save template as file".

[image: Template Manager - Edit template]

If you create new templates via external file, it will automatically set them to be saved as file. If you create new templates via the EE Control Panel, by default this option may be turned off (ignoring global settings), so you have to tick it. I'd recommend you don't mix external editing and Control Panel editing - just do it all in one or the other. If working externally, EE automatically detects new template groups and templates, mixing the 2 it often falls apart and gets confused, hence having to use the Sync templates screen.

If that is already done and you're still not seeing your frontend reflecting your external templates, 2 checks come to mind - double check the folder path is correct, and ensure you have the correct permissions.

You mentioned that you copied the templates into the folder [manually] - don't do that, instead follow the steps above: edit the template in EE and tick the save as template. After saving, if that doesn't create the file, then you have a pathing/permissions issue.

Also, you mentioned "two templates to template folder" - just to confirm: templates don't just sit in the templates folder, they sit in an initial subfolder called "default_site" (if not using MSM) then there are subfolders within this based on the template group they're in. Template group folders have the extension .group, then the template files themselves have the extension .html. Again if you've saved the template via the EE Control Panel, then you'd see this structure created for you.

Comment: I am using ExpressionEngine v2.10.1 and it has not any option of save template as file please give me your mail id. or ping me on abhaystacks@gmail.com i am very much confused.

Comment: It's in Design -> Templates -> Template Manager, click on a template to edit it (not it's preferences), then scroll to bottom and you'll see the same as my grab above. If the tickbox is not shown, then you've not set your global config correctly, go back to Template Manager and select "Global Template Preferences" and ensure "Save Templates as Files" is set to Yes.